# Does obfuscation ever change variable/function types

Tags: obfuscation

is there certain obfuscation techniques that might change variable types? Ie. C gives you more than enough string to hang yourself with and you can add a char and int. Will code obfuscation ever change a char to an int or convert any other variable types?

Comment: If obfuscation did that, it would change the functionality of the code, and clearly that would not be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an example for type changes, but the [entry about software obfuscation on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) says:

> In addition, tools known as obfuscators can provide automated obfuscation to compiled applications that make reverse engineering more difficult for people and machines but do not alter the behavior of the obfuscated application.

According to this, any application may be the output of an obfuscator that has the same behavior as the original application.